# LLVM not inserting function call inside doInitialization() method

Tags: llvm

The following code snippet compiles fine, yet the resulting bitcode does not have any calls to `instrument_global_variable` inserted. However, there are global variables listed in the code I am running on. Why doesn't the LLVM pass insert any instrumentation in this case?

```
bool doInitialization(Module &M) override {
    for (auto &global : M.getGlobalList()) {
        if (isa<GlobalVariable>(global)) {
            errs() << "[G]: " << global << '\n';
            auto &Ctx = M.getContext();
            IRBuilder<> builder(Ctx);
            Constant *instrument_func = M.getOrInsertFunction("instrument_global_variable", Type::getVoidTy(Ctx), Type::getInt64Ty(Ctx), NULL);
            Value* args[] = {global.getOperand(0)};
            builder.CreateCall(instrument_func, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [doc](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-doinitialization-callgraph-method) starting with the `CallGraphSCCPass` pass, you will notice a pattern with the phrasing of `doInitialization()` methods.

They state that they can do mostly anything that the main `runOn` method is not allowed to do. So, since `ModulePass` can do pretty much anything, the use of `doInitialization` is limited to user specific actions (e.g. user data allocations, etc).

Moreover, it runs only once will the pass is alive, so if you're processing multiple modules, it would have skipped all but the first, which would have made no sense (although, AFAIK, there is no capability in `opt` to process multiple bitcode files per execution). Thus, even its documentation is omitted (a mistake IMHO).

I understand that you'd like to do this once per module, so I guess the best place *is* the `runOn` method. If you really require it to be separate from other kind of processing, you could leave it in a pass by itself and require it by your other passes down the line.